# How can any sample be drawn from a continuous distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, continuous-data

Since the probability of a continuous variable $X$ assume any particular value is always zero, how can any sample be obtained from such distribution? How can we obtain, e.g., the set of observations $\{0.3, 1.1, -0.5, -0.6, 0.9\}$ from a normal distribution, when $P(X = 0.3) = P(X = 1.1) = \ldots = 0$?

Is this happening because of measurement errors? Like there will never be any human weighing exactly 200 lbs, a bottle with exactly 1L of water, and no software capable of generate any number with infinite decimals.

Comment: One solution--not really a very good one theoretically or computationally, but an insightful one--is to view all such data as implicitly reflecting *interval* measurements.  Standard engineering rules of thumb, for instance, state that a value reported as "$0.3$" with one decimal place ought to be considered as the interval from $0.25$ to $0.35.$  The correct probability to ascribe to "$0.3$" therefore is the chance that $X$ lies somewhere in this interval: and that chance is always nonzero when $X$ has any (nondegenerate) Normal distribution.

Comment: Another solution, inspired by your title, is to divide and conquer.  To draw a sample from *any* distribution start by flipping a coin.  If it's heads, focus on the upper half of the distribution; otherwise, focus on the lower half.  In either case you are now working with a *truncated* distribution, but it's exactly the same kind of object.  So repeat: keep flipping coins and choosing halves.  Very soon your truncated distribution will be indistinguishable from a constant value, so declare the process finished and use that value.

Comment: Thank you very much, @whuber. That was precisely the kind of answer I was needing. The word 'truncated was in my mind when I was writing my question.

By the way, I don't know if it was you, but my question was assigned as a duplicate. I read the related question and all the answers, but I do not agree on this linking. My question was more 'technical' than theoretical: precisely on _how_ the sample could exist, just as you answered.

Comment: I did not close your question as a duplicate, Lenora.  When I encountered it, it had already been closed. Feeling that you might be looking for some expansion on the duplicate posts, I offered my comments.

Comment: Thank you once again.